# How to add a whole package to transport request by code?

Tags: abap

My task is to do all these steps programmatically:

- Create a new transport request, I managed to do this with  `TR_INSERT_REQUEST_WITH_TASKS`
- Add package content to the newly created transport, this is the part I am stuck in.
- Release the transport, I managed to do this with `TR_RELEASE_REQUEST`

My problem is that I can manually add the package to the transport request via transaction `SE03` and then release it with FM `TR_RELEASE_REQUEST`, but that is not the goal, everything from step 1 to 3 has to happen in one program execution if anyone can guide me how to do step 2 it would be very helpful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program, you must :

- First get the list of objects which belong to the package, via the table `TADIR` (object in columns `PGMID`, `OBJECT`, `OBJ_NAME`, and package in column `DEVCLASS`)
- And add these objects to the task or transport request via the non-released function modules `TRINT_APPEND_COMM` or `TR_APPEND_TO_COMM_OBJS_KEYS`.

Comment: Thanks this was the answer to my problem!

Answer (score 1):

To add the whole project into request you must first select all the objects from package and add them one by one. You can do it like this:

```
DATA: l_trkorr  TYPE trkorr,
      l_package TYPE devclass VALUE 'ZPACKAGE'.

cl_pak_package_queries=>get_all_subpackages( EXPORTING im_package     = l_package
                                             IMPORTING et_subpackages = DATA(lt_descendant) ).

INSERT VALUE cl_pak_package_queries=>ty_subpackage_info( package = l_package ) INTO TABLE lt_descendant.

SELECT pgmid, object, obj_name FROM tadir
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_segw_objects)
   FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @lt_descendant
 WHERE devclass = @lt_descendant-package.

DATA(instance) = cl_adt_cts_management=>create_instance( ).

LOOP AT lt_segw_objects ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_obj>).
  TRY.
      instance->insert_objects_in_wb_request( EXPORTING pgmid        = <fs_obj>-pgmid
                                                        object       = <fs_obj>-object
                                                        obj_name     = CONV trobj_name( <fs_obj>-obj_name )
                                              IMPORTING result       = DATA(result)
                                                        request      = DATA(request)
                                              CHANGING  trkorr       = l_trkorr ).
    CATCH cx_adt_cts_insert_error.
  ENDTRY.
ENDLOOP.
```

Note, that you can**not** add objects that are already locked in another request, it will give you *cx_adt_cts_insert_error* exception. There is no way to unlock objects programmatically, only via SE03 tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can check code behind, **Write Transport Entry** in SE80 right click on package menu.

Comment: I am sorry but that is not the goal, i am trying to execute it in the backend with a report, not manually.

Comment: I try to say that, you can find code behind this button and use code in your own implementation. Sandra shared exact FM for you.

Comment: Yes thank you i have managed to find what i need after debugging the button!