# Removing custom package and its contents programmatically?

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I'm in an attempt to provide an automatized way for removal of customer package ( and all it's objects ). For that purpose, I'm using FM's for creation of transport order - TRINT_INSERT_NEW_COMM , adding the objects - TRINT_INSERT_COMM and releasing the transport order - TRINT_RELEASE_REQUEST.

Preparation step is extracting from TADIR all objects where devclass is the desired object. Afterwards looping the entries from TADIR and based on the object type i'm adding them in suitable internal tables for E071K and E071 in simple CASE-WHEN.

```
CASE <ls_tadir>-object.
WHEN 'TABU'.
  ls_e071k-trkorr = gv_trkorr.
  ls_e071k-pgmid  = <ls_tadir>-pgmid.
  ls_e071k-object = 'TABU'.
  ls_e071k-objname = <ls_tadir>-obj_name.
  ls_e071k-as4pos = '000001'.
  ls_e071k-mastertype = 'TABU'.
  ls_e071k-mastername = <ls_tadir>-obj_name.
  ls_e071k-tabkey     = '*'.
  ls_e071k-objfunc    = 'D'.
  APPEND ls_e071k TO lt_e071k.

  lv_count = ls_e071-as4pos + 1.

  ls_e071-trkorr = gv_trkorr.
  ls_e071-as4pos = '000001'.
  ls_e071-pgmid = <ls_tadir>-pgmid.
  ls_e071-object = 'TABU'.
  ls_e071-obj_name = <ls_tadir>-obj_name.
  ls_e071-objfunc = 'D'.

  APPEND ls_e071 TO lt_e071.
WHEN 'TABL'.
    ls_e071k-trkorr = gv_trkorr.
    ls_e071k-pgmid  = <ls_tadir>-pgmid.
    ls_e071k-object = 'TABL'.
    ls_e071k-objname = <ls_tadir>-obj_name.
    ls_e071k-as4pos = '000001'.
    ls_e071k-mastertype = 'TABL'.
    ls_e071k-mastername = <ls_tadir>-obj_name.
    ls_e071k-tabkey     = '*'.
    ls_e071k-objfunc    = 'D'.
    APPEND ls_e071k TO lt_e071k.

  lv_count = ls_e071-as4pos + 1.

  ls_e071-trkorr = gv_trkorr.
  ls_e071-as4pos = '000001'.
  ls_e071-pgmid = <ls_tadir>-pgmid.
  ls_e071-object = 'TABL'.
  ls_e071-obj_name = <ls_tadir>-obj_name.
  ls_e071-objfunc = 'D'.

  APPEND ls_e071 TO lt_e071.

WHEN OTHERS.
  lv_count = ls_e071-as4pos + 1.

  ls_e071-trkorr = gv_trkorr.
  ls_e071-as4pos = lv_count.
  ls_e071-pgmid = <ls_tadir>-pgmid.
  ls_e071-object = <ls_tadir>-object.
  ls_e071-obj_name = <ls_tadir>-obj_name.
  ls_e071-objfunc = 'D'.

  APPEND ls_e071 TO lt_e071.
```

ENDCASE.

An important parameter is OBJFUNC to specify it as a D - Deletion. ( Maybe i'm wrong )

[image: This is how generated ToC on target system looks like]

Here is the overview in E071 table. It looks like deletion should be performed.
[image]

As it is imported into the target system where uninstallation should occur, nothing happens against those objects.

Any ideas?

Comment: regarding automating of adding to TR, check my answer here also https://stackoverflow.com/a/60167394/911419. Dunno why you call it uninstallation, it is simply package deletion

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's the way it works anymore, I believe OBJFUNC is obsolete. A few (many)versions ago, the process for deleting objects through transports changed. Instead of setting the action to Delete in the transport the transport system checks if an object exists during release, if it does not exist in the source system it will also be deleted in the target system.
So, in your scenario, you will have to delete the objects in the source system for the transport to also delete it in the target system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would do as suggested - "Delete from Source system -> Transport TR to Target system", if it was not in play more than 800 objects within the package. Therefore I was exploring an option for automating this step. But as you said OBJFUNC, unfortunately, seems to be obsolete.

Comment: You can try(!) to add your objects to the TR, release it and then delete the TADIR entries of the objects. Not existing TADIR entry means not existing object.

Comment: @futu releasing a TR ( Transport of Copies ) while having the objects yet in TADIR will be to early. Cofile/Datafile will be created in usr/sap/trans and not changed at all once afterwards i provide deletion of objects from TADIR table. At least this is my understanding or I understood something wrong ? Thanks