# Build a transport request manually in SAP-ABAP

Tags: abap

I developed an program that inserts records in 5 customizing tables and I need to build manually a transport request.
I've try this using function module TRINT_ORDER_CHOICE and TR_APPEND_TO_COMM_OBJS_KEYS and after all, looking into a TR in SE09 everything looks good, I can see all entries of all 5 tables with his keys, but when I run SCC1 in the client where I need those data, it's just fetch 1 record of the fisrt table.
I'm also tried to do a batch input of SM30 for each table but it's do not insert any record into the transport request. It was uselles do the batch input with DISMODE = N or DISMODE = A.
For my first approach I worte a class and here I share the code with a hope somebody can help me.
Here the full source code of the class that generate de transport request.

```
CLASS ZCL_INT_CREATE_TR DEFINITION
PUBLIC
CREATE PUBLIC .

PUBLIC SECTION.
    CONSTANTS GC_CUSTOMIZING_ORDER_TYPE type TRFUNCTION value 'W' ##NO_TEXT.
    CONSTANTS GC_WORKBENCH_ORDER_TYPE type TRFUNCTION value 'K' ##NO_TEXT.
    CONSTANTS GC_CUSTOMIZING_TASK_TYPE type TRFUNCTION value 'Q' ##NO_TEXT.
    CONSTANTS GC_WORKBENCH_TASK_TYPE type TRFUNCTION value 'S' ##NO_TEXT.
    CONSTANTS GC_CUSTOMIZING_ORDER_CATEGORY type TRCATEG value 'CUST' ##NO_TEXT.
    CONSTANTS GC_WORKBENCH_ORDER_CATEGORY type TRCATEG value 'SYST' ##NO_TEXT.

    DATA GV_ORDER type TRKORR read-only .
    DATA GV_TASK type TRKORR read-only .

    METHODS CONSTRUCTOR
        importing
           !IV_ORDER_TYPE type TRFUNCTION
           !IV_TASK_TYPE type TRFUNCTION
           !IV_CATEGORY type E070-KORRDEV .

    METHODS ADD_TABLE
        importing
           !IR_DATA type ref to DATA .

    METHODS CREATE .
PROTECTED SECTION.
PRIVATE SECTION.

   types:
      BEGIN OF lty_tables,
         table TYPE REF TO data,
      END OF lty_tables .

   types: ltty_tables TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF lty_tables .

   data GO_BDC type ref to ZCL_UTL_BDC .
   data GT_TABLES type LTTY_TABLES .
   data GT_E71 type TT_E071 .
   data GT_E71K type TRN_REG_TRANS_KEYS .
   data GV_ORDER_TYPE type TRFUNCTION .
   data GV_TASK_TYPE type TRFUNCTION .
   data GV_CATEGORY type E070-KORRDEV .

   methods CALL_TR_DIALOG .
   methods FILL_E071 .
   methods FILL_E071N
       importing
          !IS_E070 type E071
          !IT_DATA type STANDARD TABLE
          !IO_STRDSCR type ref to CL_ABAP_STRUCTDESCR .
   methods TR_APPEND_TO_COMM_OBJS_KEYS .
ENDCLASS.

CLASS ZCL_INT_CREATE_TR IMPLEMENTATION.

    method ADD_TABLE.
        APPEND INITIAL LINE TO me->gt_tables ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<lfs_table>).
        <lfs_table>-table = ir_data.
    endmethod.

    METHOD call_tr_dialog.
       CALL FUNCTION 'TRINT_ORDER_CHOICE'
          EXPORTING
             wi_order_type          = me->gv_order_type
             wi_task_type           = me->gv_task_type
             wi_category            = me->gv_category
          IMPORTING
             we_order               = me->gv_order
             we_task                = me->gv_task
          TABLES
             wt_e071                = me->gt_e71
             wt_e071k               = me->gt_e71k.
    ENDMETHOD.

    method CONSTRUCTOR.
       me->gv_order_type = iv_order_type.
       me->gv_task_type = iv_task_type.
       me->gv_category = iv_category.
    endmethod.

    METHOD create.
       me->call_tr_dialog( ).
       me->fill_e071( ).
       me->tr_append_to_comm_objs_keys( ).
    ENDMETHOD.

    METHOD FILL_E071.

       DATA: lo_strucdescr TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr.
       DATA: lo_tabledescr TYPE REF TO cl_abap_tabledescr.
       FIELD-SYMBOLS: <lfs_tab> TYPE STANDARD TABLE.

       LOOP AT me->gt_tables INTO DATA(ls_table).
          TRY.
             ASSIGN ls_table-table->* TO <lfs_tab>.
             IF <lfs_tab> IS ASSIGNED.
                lo_tabledescr ?= cl_abap_elemdescr=>describe_by_data_ref( ls_table-table ).
                lo_strucdescr ?= lo_tabledescr->get_table_line_type( ).

                DATA(ls_header) = lo_strucdescr->get_ddic_header( ).

                APPEND INITIAL LINE TO me->gt_e71 ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<lfs_e71>).
                <lfs_e71>-pgmid = 'R3TR'.
                <lfs_e71>-object = 'TABU'.
                <lfs_e71>-obj_name = ls_header-tabname.
                <lfs_e71>-objfunc = 'K'.
                <lfs_e71>-as4pos = lines( me->gt_e71 ).
                <lfs_e71>-lang = sy-langu.

                me->fill_e071n( EXPORTING is_e070    = <lfs_e71>
                                          it_data    = <lfs_tab>
                                          io_strdscr = lo_strucdescr ).
             ENDIF.
          CATCH cx_sy_move_cast_error .
       ENDTRY.
    ENDLOOP.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD fill_e071n.

      DATA(lt_tab_fields) = io_strdscr->get_ddic_field_list( ).

      LOOP AT it_data ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<lfs_data>).
          APPEND INITIAL LINE TO me->gt_e71k ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<lfs_e071k>).
          <lfs_e071k>-pgmid      = is_e070-pgmid.
          <lfs_e071k>-object     = is_e070-object.
          <lfs_e071k>-objname    = is_e070-obj_name.
          <lfs_e071k>-mastertype = is_e070-object.
          <lfs_e071k>-mastername = <lfs_e071k>-objname.
          <lfs_e071k>-lang       = sy-langu." <lfs_e071k>-lang.
          LOOP AT lt_tab_fields INTO DATA(ls_field) WHERE keyflag = 'X'.
              ASSIGN COMPONENT ls_field-fieldname OF STRUCTURE <lfs_data> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<lfs_value>).
              <lfs_e071k>-tabkey     = <lfs_e071k>-tabkey && <lfs_value>.
          ENDLOOP.
      ENDLOOP.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD tr_append_to_comm_objs_keys.
      CALL FUNCTION 'TR_APPEND_TO_COMM_OBJS_KEYS'
          EXPORTING
              wi_trkorr                      = me->gv_task
          TABLES
              wt_e071                        = me->gt_e71
              wt_e071k                       = me->gt_e71k.
  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
```

Here a sample of how to use this class. I will not use the same code I used because there are 5 Z tables to create, so I will use some dummy code. Let's supose that those ztdummy1...ztdummy5 are customizing table. It's should work with any customizing table.

```
DATA: lo_tr TYPE REF TO zcl_int_create_tr.
SELECT * FROM ztdummy1 INTO TABLE @data(ltdummy1) WHERE id_dummy =  7.
SELECT * FROM ztdummy2 INTO TABLE @data(ltdummy2) WHERE id_dummy =  7.
SELECT * FROM ztdummy3 INTO TABLE @data(ltdummy3) WHERE id_dummy =  7.
SELECT * FROM ztdummy4 INTO TABLE @data(ltdummy4) WHERE id_dummy =  7.
SELECT * FROM ztdummy5 INTO TABLE @data(ltdummy5) WHERE id_dummy =  7.

CREATE OBJECT lo_tr
  EXPORTING
    iv_order_type = zcl_int_create_tr=>gc_customizing_order_type
    iv_task_type  = zcl_int_create_tr=>gc_customizing_task_type
    iv_category   = zcl_int_create_tr=>gc_customizing_order_category.

lo_tr->add_table( REF #( ltdummy1 ) ).
lo_tr->add_table( REF #( ltdummy2 ) ).
lo_tr->add_table( REF #( ltdummy3 ) ).
lo_tr->add_table( REF #( ltdummy4 ) ).
lo_tr->add_table( REF #( ltdummy5 ) ).

lo_tr->create( ).
```

Could someone please help me?

Best regards.

Ronaldo S. Vieira

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. You might rewrite it a little bit so that to make it a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thank you.

Comment: @SandraRossi, I'm sorry for the post. Now, I believe it's possible to compile the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add table rows to a TR programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672657/add-table-rows-to-a-tr-programmatically)

Comment: check also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60151674/how-to-add-a-whole-package-to-transport-request-by-code/60167394#60167394

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting all required fields in e071 and E071k ?

In both  E071/E071k  What about trkorr ?
Why is as4pos only set with E071 ?
I dont use the functions, I write direct to the tables.
When I check my code, I see special attention to as4pos in both tables.
And Trkorr is also set.

I remember when I first wrote the code, an Incorrect as4pos value/s explains the behaviour you describe.

He is a sample piece of code i've been using for some time.

```
METHODS add_tabu_entries
  IMPORTING
    i_trkorr      TYPE trkorr
    i_tablename   TYPE e071-obj_name
    i_tabkey      TYPE any 
    i_with_client TYPE flag.

 

METHOD add_tabu_entries.


    DATA: ls_e071  TYPE e071,
          ls_e071k TYPE e071k,
          l_max    TYPE ddposition,
          l_as4pos TYPE  ddposition,
          l_max_k TYPE ddposition.

    IF i_trkorr IS INITIAL.
      RETURN.
    ENDIF.

    SELECT SINGLE as4pos FROM e071 INTO l_as4pos
        WHERE trkorr = i_trkorr
        AND pgmid = 'R3TR'
        AND object = 'TABU'
        AND obj_name = i_tablename.

    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      SELECT  MAX( as4pos ) FROM e071 INTO l_max
              WHERE trkorr = i_trkorr.

      l_as4pos =  l_max + 1.

    ENDIF.

    ls_e071-trkorr  = i_trkorr.
    ls_e071-as4pos = l_as4pos.
    ls_e071-pgmid = 'R3TR'.
    ls_e071-object = 'TABU'.
    ls_e071-obj_name = i_tablename.
    ls_e071-objfunc = 'K'.

    modify e071 FROM ls_e071.   

    ls_e071k-trkorr = i_trkorr.
    ls_e071k-pgmid = 'R3TR'.
    ls_e071k-object = 'TABU'.
    ls_e071k-objname = i_tablename.
    ls_e071k-mastertype = 'TABU'.
    ls_e071k-mastername = i_tablename.

    IF i_tabkey IS NOT INITIAL.

      l_max_k = get_max_as4pos( ls_e071k ).
 
      ls_e071k-as4pos = l_max_k + 1.

      IF i_with_client = 'X'.
        CONCATENATE sy-mandt i_tabkey INTO  ls_e071k-tabkey .
      ELSE.
        ls_e071k-tabkey = i_tabkey.
      ENDIF.

      modify e071k FROM ls_e071k.

      RETURN.

    ENDIF.
   
endmethod. 


 METHOD get_max_as4pos.
    SELECT   MAX( as4pos ) FROM e071k INTO r_result
          WHERE trkorr = is_e071k-trkorr
          and pgmid = is_e071k-pgmid " 'R3TR'
          and object = is_e071k-object  "'TABU'
          and objname = is_e071k-objname " i_tablename
          and mastertype = is_e071k-mastertype    "'TABU'
          and mastername = is_e071k-mastername. "  i_tablename.

  ENDMETHOD.
```